# Unable to install Android ADT Plugin for Eclipse Helios 3.6.2

Tags: android, adt, eclipse-3.6

I am a new Android developer. While trying to install the ADT Plugin for Eclipse on a Win 7 system, I encountered this warning:

```
Warning: You are installing software that contains unsigned content. The authenticity or validity of this software cannot be established. Do you want to continue with the installation?
```

I clicked the 'OK' button to proceed, and was greeted with another pop-up window bearing the following message:

Problem occurred:

'Installing Software' has encountered a problem.

```
An error occurred while installing the items
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 10.0.1.v201103111512-110841, action=).
Failed to prepare partial IU: [R]com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 10.0.1.v201103111512-110841.
```

Rebooting my machine did not help, neither did reinstalling a fresh copy of Eclipse.

Any help will be be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I've had this problem too and I came across a few solutions that may help you.

1. Turn off your anti-virus software, some people have reported that it has been corrupting the plug-in. Redownload the plug-in and try again.
2. Turn on auto update by Eclipse -> Preferences ->Install/Update -> Automatic Update  so that all the components you are using are current. This comes from AlphaBeta's response from the following thread http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/f3e69ff660789794/b1e12e80386142d0?pli=1
3. Make sure there are no spaces in the path where you installed eclipse, if there are delete the spaces in the folder names. Another user (ericdelang@gmail.com) on the same thread said this solved the problem from him.
4. Finally, what worked for me was unzipping ADT.14.0.0.zip and copying all the files from the plugins folder in ADT.14.0.0 to the plugins folder in eclipse. I have a mac and so this means I copied the following files from the ADT.14.0.0.zip archive:

   ```
   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_14.0.0.v201110171935-205994.jar
   com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms_14.0.0.v201110171935-205994.jar
   com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer_14.0.0.v201110171935-205994.jar
   com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview_14.0.0.v201110171935-205994.jar
   overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay_14.0.0.v201110171935-205994.jar`
   ```

   into the folder /Applications/eclipse/plugins. Now install the plugin normally like it says on the developer.android.com page.

Comment: Thank you very much, the fourth solution did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

installing it via site or archive? try changing the way you are installing. I installed with archive and it worked well, sometimes it gives problem in installation via update site due to firewall issues.